# Questions About Flickr: on vs. off topic

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Thoughts on whether questions about Flickr (specifically about certain features/functionality) would be on or off topic for the site?

I would think it's on-topic, but it's not strictly about the craft of photography or editing...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think questions about using the Flickr site would be better on WebApps. Questions on Flickr so far as preparing photos for upload, uploading photos, and the like, would be suitable here.

Comment: Seems like a good approach to me...

Answer (score 0):

Questions related to how to use flickr/A.N.Other online photo-sharing site/etc. should be put on webapps. What I think we should keep are questions that are related to photographers putting their work online, and issues related to that. Perhaps we need a tag to group questions such as `[online-sharing]` maybe?